# How to set proxy in git with email as username?

Tags: bash, git, github, unix, proxy

I know to set a proxy in git open a command prompt and run the following commands replacing **USERNAME**, **PASSWORD**, **PROXY_ADDRESS**, and **PROXY_PORT** with your network's information:

`git config --global --add http.proxy http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXY_ADDRESS:PROXY_PORT`

`git config --global --add https.proxy http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXY_ADDRESS:PROXY_PORT`

but problem is that I have my email as a username that is in form of `username@host.com` and password is in the form of `<some-text>@<some-digit>` so everytime I try to use git it given me error like this `Could not resolve proxy: 1001@10.151.0.16` and nothing else.

Comment: try to urlencode `@`, e.g. `<some-text>%40<some-digit>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproxy%5D+encode+special+characters

Answer (score -1):

change socks5 proxy,is a better way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).